# Boolean reduction of $AB+(B+C)BC$

Tags: boolean-algebra

> Reduce this Boolean expression
>   $$AB+(B+C)BC$$
>   Please express step by step process to understand clearly.

Comment: ??????????????:

Comment: Did you understand the question?

Comment: Nah.. that's what those question marks indicate. I m totally clueless about what your problem is..

Comment: Can you reduce that expression?

Comment: The expression appears to be fully reduced.  What are you looking for?

Comment: This is Expression [(AB)+((B+C)(BC))]

Comment: I mean, you can rewrite it as $AB+B^2C+BC^2$ or $B(A + BC + C^2)$ but I  don't see why either or those would be described as more "reduced".

Comment: @Thelonewolfisbackbaby... note the boolean-algebra tag. Dhani, it would be better to point out in the question that your variables come from a Boolean algebra, not, say, the real numbers!

Comment: Now this make some sense :-)

Comment: @Dhani for you, does + denote "or" or "xor"? That is, do we have $x+x=x$ or $x+x=0$?

Comment: Yes we have X+x=x

Answer (score 4):

Use:

**Absorption**

$P(P+Q) = P$

With that:

$$AB + (B + C)BC = AB + BC$$ ($B$ absorbs $B+C$)

And if you want, you can use Distribution to make that $B(A + C)$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
AB+(B+C)BC &= AB + B^2C + BC^2\\
& = AB + BC + BC\\
& = AB + BC
\end{align*}

Comment: Sigh... did the downvoters miss the Boolean algebra tag too?

Comment: Weird indeed ...